# Build Version Code O not being recognized correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-8.0-oreo, notification-channel

I have this code snippet for my local notifications to work on Oreo devices.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, 
            CHANNEL_NAME,
            level);

    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

On my window desktop this is fine, no issues. However on my macbook, lint complains about NotificationChannel requiring SDK 26 and my min is 21. However if I change the version check to

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26)
```

the error goes away. I've tried restarting Android studio, clean/rebuild. Nothing works. When I do code inspection and use the suggested hints, its changing the Version_Code to 26. Its kinda bothering me having it act different on my 2 machines but same exact code. Anyone else seen this issue before?

```
compileSdkVersion = 26
buildToolsVersion = "26.0.2"

minSdkVersion = 21
targetSdkVersion = 26
```

Comment: did you set targetSdkVersion and if you set what is it

Comment: Same question as above but for your compileSdkVersion, which needs to be [at least 26](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES#O) for this field to be available to you.

Comment: I added my gradle statements. Theyre the same on both computers, only the mac complains.

Comment: I reinstalled android studio and the error went away. I think the version number had something to do with it. It was on 2.3.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.1: Erroneous unresolved references in editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49545037/android-studio-3-1-erroneous-unresolved-references-in-editor)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with android studio 3.2.1 after I switched from an old project to another. Very annoying. I solved with these steps:

- Delete {projectDir}/.idea/libraries folder
- File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
- File -> Sync Project with File System

Answer (score 0):

Oreo is android 8.
Instead your code, using below code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, 
            CHANNEL_NAME,
            level);
    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```