# Android Studio has lost intelliSens in Kotlin multiplatform project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

I am working on KMP project and I have a problem with accessing to my shared module source files from `app` module.

Android studio complains about everything, what are related to the commonMain source files (shared module),  and says `Unresolved reference: exampleVariableFromSharedModule` and intellisence is also lost.

When I run the project, everything works fine and there is no compilation issues at all.

I'm trying to fix that issue almost hole week.

Tried:

1. cleaning the project,
2. invalidate & restart
3. used different versions of Kotlin.
4. open the project in two different versions of android studio (4.1.1
   & 4.2 preview) with no luck.
5. removed the shared module from `settings.gradle` & `build.gradle` synced, then restore.
6. File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings
7. Disable / enable kotlin plugin
8. removed .idea and all build folders

**Last thing that I tried:**

Uninstalled all Android Studios and its related folders, downloaded it again but still getting the same problem.

Comment: Just another idea: try deleting your `.idea` folder (make a backup before, you'll lose your run configurations among other things), and reimporting the project.

Comment: Tried it and result is same, thanks anyway

Comment: This happened to me a few times, it goes away eventually. Sometimes it's a cache issue, sometimes it's an error in your build script, sometimes it's downright a bug. You can always try the ultimate solution: reinstalling AS, although I don't recommend it, because it takes a long time. Otherwise there's a multitude of duplicate questions that might have other answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31712046/5288316), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49545037/5288316), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5905896/5288316), etc...

Comment: tried all of them and still got same problem, now I'll try to uninstall all Android studios

Comment: There are a few [bug reports](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-31052) that can be related, might be you are hitting one of these issues

Comment: Hello, @JemoMgebrishvili! Can you please give me an update about this situation? Is the problem still here, or you managed to work around it somehow?

Comment: yes in my case I had a one dependncy inside common scope
  implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:android-paging-extensions:1.2.1" and removing that fixed the problem